# responsive images with fixed space

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to create a responsive gallery with images of various dimensions. The idea is to have 5 square divs of the same size on full screen, each image is centered both horizontally and vertically, scaled to fit with some padding (proportional, according to window size). Spacing among divs is the same both horizontal and vertical (again proportional (%) based on window size  - to have a nice tidy view. There is min and max size of divs so when min size of divs in one row is reached they are reordered, meaning the last one on row 1 will move to row 2 etc, keeping the fixed (proportional) spacing.

Is this even possible with just CSS?

The closest example I could find is this: 
    `<code>http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGwwEB</code>` but I was not able to turn it to what I need.

Comment: what code do you have that you've tried so far?

Comment: just a combination of various examples, nothing that works

Comment: this is possible using a mixture of flex and padding top but your question is too broad and incomplete

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: so far this https://jsfiddle.net/72k5w2wc/1/

Answer (score -2):

if you are using bootstrap classes then write

```
<img src="" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
```